# CNN Image Classification: It gives me always the same prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, jupyter-notebook, conv-neural-network

I'm new on this field, still learning and I'm sorry if it is considered as silly questions.
So recently I tried to learn image classification using Python and TensorFlow. I followed tutorial on some videos. But I have some problems in my code, because when I tried my model, the validation loss tends to increase, while my validation accuracy keeps fluctuating. When I tried to predict my sample image, it keeps giving me the same prediction. My images in my datasets are 730 images in total.

And here is my code for making the prediction:

```
import cv2
import tensorflow as tf

CATEGORIES = ["Bike", "Car"]
IMAGE_SIZE = 50

def prepare(filepath):
    image_array = cv2.imread(filepath, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    image_array = image_array/255.0
    new_image_array = cv2.resize(image_array, (IMAGE_SIZE,IMAGE_SIZE))
    return new_image_array.reshape(-1, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 1)

model = tf.keras.models.load_model("prototype.model")

prediction = model.predict([prepare('car.jpg')])
print( CATEGORIES[int(prediction[0][0])] )
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: Are you running it for only 3 epochs or is that just for this question?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time. Yes I only run it for 3 epochs. I don't know whether it affects my output or not. When I tried to run it for 10 epochs, it has the same pattern, after each 3epochs, my validation loss tends to increase and my validation accuracy is the other way. The total images for my trained model are 730 images.

Comment: I am not sure about the complexity of your images, and the number of images also seem low, especially if there is large variation, if possible please add a link to your dataset, also , if they are complex, 2 conv layers might not be enough. If it fits, the problem is most likely the hyperparameters. Also, while filling your data arr, dont use `pass` with the `except`, atleast log/print your exception

Comment: My datasets are consist of car images and bike images. Here is the link to my dataset :https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qDFY19aPXmFTh2gtyjF9ByvMc1p5ZOZ_?usp=sharing
I have tried by using 4 conv layers, but it keeps giving me the same output.
Should i replace the pass?

Comment: This code is almost identical, I guess it should help you in solving the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61555205/convolutional-neural-network-seems-to-be-randomly-guessing/61556227#61556227

Comment: Your code to make a prediction reads in a model called "prototype.model". Are you always getting the same predictions because you're loading the same model every time? Predictions need to be made using the model that you trained.

Comment: @littleO hello, sorry for late response. The problem was not with my model, but It seems to be from my code. A fellow tutor in this forum has helped me to solve the problem, so it's good now :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once had a similar problem. Since you need to classify images as either "Bike" or "Car", try changing your final output layer to,

```
model.add(Dense(2))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

If it still doesn't work, try `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` instead as your `loss`.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your time.
I am using your suggestion now, the validation loss and validation accuracy are in good direction. The validation loss keep getting smaller, and the validation accuracy is higher not fluctuating anymore.
But my prediction is always giving me the same output regardless the images input.

Comment: How much is your, accuracy and validation accuracy

Comment: 1st epoch - Val_loss : 0.9574 - Val_acc: 0.4384 - accuracy: 0.6347,
2nd epoch - Val_loss : 0.2298 - Val_acc: 0.9589 - accuracy: 0.7884,
3rd epoch - Val_loss : 0.4229 - Val_acc: 0.8356 - accuracy: 0.8052,
4th epoch - Val_loss : 0.1437 - Val_acc: 0.9863 - accuracy: 0.8463,
5th epoch - Val_loss : 0.0712 - Val_acc: 1.0000 - accuracy: 0.8432.
those are my result

Comment: @bodrov, can you try `np.argmax(prediction[0], axis=-1)` in place of  `prediction[0][0]`

Comment: @PratikKumar Hi! Thanks for your time. I'm using your suggestion now. But it is still giving me the same output. I am using a car image, but it's still giving me bike output.

Comment: @bodrov, did you use it in combination with the solution provided by Akash ?

Comment: Yes, I used it with akash's suggestion too. It still give me the same output result. When I tred to print my prediction, I got this value "[[0.8155083  0.18449168]]". Does it mean the percentage of my picture from those possible 2 categories?

Comment: Yes it does mean percentage

Comment: @bodrov, yes it the confidence on the 2 classes, `[[0.8155083 0.18449168]]` indicates that the algo is 81% confident that the image belongs to class 0 and 18% confident that it belongs to class 1.

Comment: looks like you are nearly there. try `np.argmax(prediction[0][0], axis=-1)`

Comment: `prediction = model.predict([prepare('car.jpg')])` , prepare('car.jpeg') is already a 4 dim array, why are you enclosing it in sq. brackets. It should probably throw error

Comment: @PratikKumar I have tried your suggestion, and when I printed my prediction of bike Image, it gives me this value "[[0.6742608  0.32573918]".
When I printed the car image, it gives me this value "[[0.01642671 0.98357326]]"
I'm pretty sure it has already recognizes the car image. However, it is still giving me Bike as an output

Comment: @AkashKarnatak Thank You for the advice.  I have removed the square bracket, but it is still giving me the same output.

Comment: In your above comment you said   `my prediction of bike Image, it gives me this value "[[0.6742608 0.32573918]". When I printed the car image, it gives me this value "[[0.01642671 0.98357326]]` these predictions are correct so whats wrong then. Just print `CATEGORIES[np.argmax(prediction[0][0])]`

Comment: Yes, I agree with You about the prediction. But when I print the categories, it gives me "bike" output as always, even though I put a car image there. So that's what make me confuse.

Comment: Tell me the output of these two statements `print(prediction)` and `print(CATEGORIES[np.argmax(prediction[0][0])])` and use car as input

Comment: this is the value that I got for print(prediction): [[0.10215805 0.89784193]]
and for print(CATEGORIES[np.argmax(prediction[0][0])]): bike

Comment: Try `print(CATEGORIES[np.argmax(prediction[0])])`  it will give you cat

Comment: @AkashKarnatak Your recent suggestion with print(CATEGORIES[np.argmax(prediction[0])]) has helped me to solve my problem. Right now it gives me the correct value. Thank You so much with your help. I really do appreciate your help.
also thank You PraktikKumar for your help too. I feel relieved now.